# Apply group by on Sharepoint Search results

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-search, grouping, kql

I am struggling with figuring out how to apply group by on SharePoint 2013 search results. I am using angular JS to display the results using SharePoint restful endpoint for search service. I am using KQL (keyword query language) but unable to see any method how I can group the search results on users.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot group the results through REST. I believe the best you can do is sort by and then group the results client side.